# Custom ActiveAdmin Scope to display books without a tag

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, tags, activeadmin

I am using ActiveAdmin in my rails app. Everything works great, but now I am trying to create a scope that will display books without a tag.

I have created a method in my Book model to help me do this, but I cannot use it inside my ActiveAdmin scope.

```
I keep getting 
undefined method `book_tags?'
```

**How can I create a scope that will only show books without a tag?**

**Model**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_mappings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :book_mappings

  ###Find books without a tag
  def book_tags?
    tags.any?
  end

end

class BookMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :tag

end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :book_mappings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, through: :book_mappings

end
```

ActiveAdmin

```
ActiveAdmin.register Book do

  ###Scope to shows all Books          
  scope :all, :default => true

  ###book_tags? does now work, I keep getting undefined method `book_tags?'
  scope :books_without_tags do |book|
    book.book_tags?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is undefined because scopes are class level. The `book` argument is actually an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. You can refine it in the block. You could use scopes or even class methods.

You could do something along the lines:

```
class Book < AR::Base
  scope :without_tags, -> { where.not(id: BookMapping.distinct.pluck(:book_id)) }
end

ActiveAdmin.register Book do
  scope :all, default: true
  scope :without_tags
end
```

Comment: I had to add a ")" but everything works great. Thank you so much :)